# Converting types in OOP Perl program

Tags: perl, oop, casting

I am experimenting with something I like to do in Perl but I am getting a strange output and I can't figure out why. 
Basically I have 2 classes. A is the base and B inherits from A. 
I issue prints to the screen to track the program and result. On the last stage I am trying to cast A Type to B Type and to use a function declared in B.

For some reason this whole program runs twice - the output is duplicated - though i run the program once. 
Is this a real issue? and why does it happen?

I am pasting here my code and output. 
The file name is A.pm;
Running command: 'perl A.pm'

```
package A;


sub new
{
        my ($class) = shift;
        my $self = {};
        bless $self, $class;
}

sub P
{
        my $self = shift;
        print "P:A\n";
}

sub PA
{
        my $self=shift;
        print "PA:A\n";
}  
1;

###############################
package B;
use base 'A';

sub new
{
        my ($class) = shift;
        my $self = {};
        bless $self, $class;
}

sub P
{
        my $self=shift;
        print "P:B\n";
}

sub PB
{
        my $self=shift;
        print "PB:B\n";
}

1;
###############################

package main;

$o = B->new;
$o->P();
$o->PA();
$o->PB();
$o = A->new;
$o->P();
$o->PA();
print "Casting\n";
bless $o , 'B';
$o->PB();
print "End\n";
```

Output:

```
[#~]perl A.pm
P:B
PA:A
PB:B
P:A
PA:A
Casting
PB:B
End
P:B
PA:A
PB:B
P:A
PA:A
Casting
PB:B
End
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce this but it happens only when the filename is `A.pm` and not when it is `A.pl`. I believe what is happening is that if you tell the Perl interpreter that it is a module, the entire file is executed upon loading (including the main package) and then executed again. It's been a long while since I delved into Perl details but IIRC modules (`.pm`) are not intended to be directly executed from the command line.  Someone with more recent experience might provide a better technical explanation, which is why I didn't post this as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the deprecated `base`, do `use parent -norequire => 'A';`

One of the defects of base that caused it to be superseded by parent is that there's no good way to tell it not to try loading the base class module.

Comment: So if I understand you corectly - when Perl interpreter read 'package B' he looks for the A module and load A.pm. This causes the main package to invoke - this is the first output. Then the real run for the main package execute.  This also explains why it was reproduces only in A.pm and not in A.pl

Comment: The `use base` is loading and running A.pm, yes.  If you had warnings enabled the way you should, you would see subroutine redefined warnings for all you methods.

Comment: Ok. Good to know. Thanks for your help.